# Mobile screen mirroring and even injection

Tags: live-connect-sdk

Can I use Connect SDK to mirror mobile screen (both iOS and Android) and event injection? My aim is to stream mobile screen to browser and injecting events based on user interaction (on browser).

I don't want to ROOT/Jailbreak.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For Android devices I know you can.

Use [Vysor (Beta)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor-beta/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) - A google chrome extension that mirrors android device to PC/MAC via usb. And you can interact directly on the mirrored screen on your system and the events will get replicated on the physical device instantly.

It connects and transitions super fast. Only small problem is it takes a second to display high resolution (a little blurry when moving fast but no lags)

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have check the vysor, its great and works smoothly. Its not opensource. I am developing my own solution. MediaProjection APIs are hope. Thanks.